# In Enterprise Architect, how to add print lines to the UML diagram?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to see how the UML diagram is divided up for printing, so that I can rearrange the diagram better to fitting entire blocks to a page.

I want to do something like the following interms of dividing up the diagram for printing.
Obviously after seeing how it would print, I would want to rearrange to blocks.

- CTRL+A mark all and then paste it complete into Paint is best option for viewing... Windows Photo Viewer

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Diagram's Properties dialog and on the "Diagram" tab there is an option to "Show Page Border (Current Diagram)".